# Changing size of an object in Action Script 3 gaming

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a beginner at Action Script 3 and currently developing a basic game of bouncing ball. The game runs perfectly with a ball bouncing and changes direction with a mouse click, as well as its color. However, now I wish to make certain changes, such as, while the game is in progress; I would want the ball's size to be tiny and as the game is being played, the ball expands. I've shared my code below, what specifically, I'm required to do at this point. Any suggestions?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;



public class Main extends MovieClip {
    private var ball:Ball = new Ball();
    private var ballSpeed, cf: int;
    private var isLeft, isUp, isLand: Boolean;

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        createBall();
        ballSpeed = 5;
        isLeft = false;
        isUp = false;
        isLand = true;
        cf = 1;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeDirection);

    }

    private function changeDirection(m:MouseEvent){

        if(isLand){
            isLand = false;
        } else {
            isLand = true;
        }

        cf += 1;

        if (cf > ball.totalFrames){
            cf = 1;
        }
        ball.gotoAndStop(cf);
    }

    private function createBall(){
        ball.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
        ball.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
        addChild(ball);





    }




    private function frameHandler(e:Event){

    if(isLand){
            if((ball.x + ball.width * .5)  < stage.stageWidth && !isLeft) {
                ball.x += ballSpeed;
                }
            if((ball.x + ball.width * .5) >=stage.stageWidth) {
                isLeft = true;
            }
            if((ball.x - ball.height * .5) > 0 && isLeft) {
                ball.x -= ballSpeed;
            }
            if((ball.x - ball.width * .5) <= 0){
                    isLeft = false;
        }
    }
    if(!isLand){
            if((ball.y + ball.height * .5) < stage.stageHeight && !isUp){
            ball.y += ballSpeed;
            }
            if((ball.y + ball.height * .5) >= stage.stageHeight){
                isUp = true;
            }
            if((ball.y - ball.height * .5) > 0 && isUp){
                ball.y -= ballSpeed;
            }
            if((ball.y - ball.width * .5) <= 0){
                isUp = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a couple of lines:

```
private function frameHandler(e:Event):void
{
    ball.scaleX += 0.01;
    ball.scaleY = ball.scaleX;
```

So, each frame the ball will grow by 1%, so at the frame rate of 25 the ball will be twice as big in 4 seconds, trice as big in 8 seconds, and so on.